# How to create REST APIs for google firestore collection data using nodejs SDK

Tags: node.js, rest, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin, firebase-security

I need to create REST APIs for crud operations on google firestore data.

API1: List collection docs or read a particular document

API2: Create a new document under a collection

API3: Update a document

API4: Delete document

Multiple apps will share the same firestore project.

- Base Collection name: MyCompany
- Sub Document: MyApp1
- Sub Collection name: ErrorMessage
- Sub Document: {"error":"Unauthorized"}

Firestore data looks like:

- MyCompany.MyApp1.ErrorMessage
- MyCompany.MyApp2.ReferalCodes
- MyCompany.MyApp3.AnotherCollection

All apps should share the same firestore instance but can access only their respective collections.

I'm planning to add a request parameter in the header("appidentifier": "MyApp1") to identify from which app the request comes from.

Requirements (via API call):

1. one app should not access collection/data of other apps
2. need to restrict permissions like app1 can only read the data, app2 can do both read and write.

Queries/Questions:

1. which node module will be suit for this (firebase-admin or firebase or @google-cloud/firestore)
2. Do we need to create and manage multiple firestore client instance? (admin or client instance)?
3. Give some design of how can we manage rules and firestore client instance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the solution here:

1. Create firestore admin instance using firebase-admin npm

   let adminInst = return await admin.initializeApp({
               credential: admin.credential.cert()
           }, 'admininstance1');
2. Generate custom token using 'uuid': App1

   await adminInst.auth().createCustomToken('App1')
           .then(function (customToken) {
               console.log(customToken);
           }).catch(async (error) => {
           });
3. Create client instance using 'firebase' npm for App1 and authenticate using custom token (step 2)

   let clientInst = await firebase.initializeApp(, 'App1');
4. Generate custom token using 'uuid': App2
5. Create client instance using 'firebase' npm for App2 and authenticate using custom token (step 4)